# Select row with max child rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table post and another table views, a post has many views while a view belongs to only one post. Now how do I select a post which has the most views, i.e. the post with max views when compared to the other post using mysql?

**EDIT**

More complicated scenario, a topic table that has many posts, and the posts can have many topics too, now how do i fetch for each topic, pick the most viewed post using mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  p.id as post, 
  Count(v.Id) as views
FROM posts p INNER JOIN views v on p.Id = v.postId
GROUP BY p.Id
ORDER BY views DESC
LIMIT 0, 1
```

Comment: ok i have a more complicated scenario, there is a topics table which has many posts and the posts can have many topics too, now for each topic, fetch the post with the most views, and thanks btw  for the solution, worked!